# Foursquare dilemna

Tags: foursquare

Who should I contact to report a problem with my Foursquare account? I am a business owner and the foursquare account for my restaurant seems like it started off as another local eatery . It has the correct business name but the telephone number is from the other place and early reviews are from the other place as well. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If the business that started off as another local eatery is your own you can claim it as your own.Just go to the business page and on the right side there should be a box saying:

> Is this your business? Claim it now.

Click now and there will be some steps to follow in order to validate your ownership.